# what encoding has 256 characters (not sha256)

Tags: encoding, hash

I'm looking at a site, and looking at the password param sent on a post request, it is some kind of hash/encoding. The password i entered was bigfella32, obviously this wasn't my actual password! Here is what it looks like:
`80449f5b5bd63f79000d0840e8f5c636d49835a8aa05636479a5492d8d0c4b2ad57672fdb8f5deca4659bd37066be7ff4de237cc8dee594b35a965c52327901a9602ac167386025dcb898ec5598ea9f320451433965a987884ffeff790e45e00ca75947f8b7184db2c9c225e6b417982ef95cd28462ea4c30b957ccd62c7fce6`
I thought it was sha256 because it is 256 chars long, but apparently sha256 only produces a 64 long char set. How can i tell what kind of encoding/hash is being used, and what is the encoding/hash being used.

Comment: Some kind of 1,024-bit hash. But it's impossible to know which without either cracking it, or getting the source code.

Comment: What do you mean “which” @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: It could literally be anything. But ideally, it's 1024bits of cryptographically secure randomness that has absolutely nothing to do with your actual password.

Comment: Oof that’s what I don’t like to hear